# How sorted python dictionary while value is list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict like this:

```
d = {
    "Meter": ["000413031", "000413032", "000413034", "000413035"],
    "Account": ["314113801", "314113802", "314114140", "314114221"],
    "AcceptedDate": ["20210226", "20210226", "20210226", "20210226"],
    "EulaVersion": ["2018v01FXRSSWO", "2018v01FXRSSWO", "2018v01FXRSSWO", "2018v01FXRSSWO"],
    "SoftwareVersion": ["FXRS1810", "FXRS1810", "FXRS1810", "FXRS1810"],
    "CompanyName": ["SN2000 TEST", "SN2000 TEST", "SN2000 TEST", "SN2000 TEST"],
    "MachGuid": ["{B2B94738-B031-46B2-9D94-F54EEF46BE82}", "{B2B94738-B031-46B2-9D94-F54EEF46BE82}", "{B2B94738-B031-46B2-9D94-F54EEF46BE82}", " {B2B94738 - B031 - 46 B2 - 9 D94 - F54EEF46BE82}"]
}
```

Because I need to dramatically insert it into db, so I first get all the column names by:

```
keys = ','.join(d.keys())
```

and I get:

```
Meter,Account,AcceptedDate,EulaVersion,SoftwareVersion,CompanyName,MachGuid
```

And this is just what I want.

The value of the dict are all lists.

so I need get it one by one.

When I tried:

```
test =','.join(str(d[x][0]) for x in sorted(d))
```

which means just get the first value in the list,but I received:

```
20210226,314113801,SN2000 TEST,2018v01FXRSSWO,{B2B94738-B031-46B2-9D94-F54EEF46BE82},000413031,FXRS1810
```

This is not in the order.Any friend can help?

Comment: Why are you building strings? Are you trying to do this insertion operation by constructing SQL text? That's unsafe and unnecessary - use parameterized statements.

Comment: "Because I need to dramatically insert it into db"-- SQL injection sounds pretty dramatic

Comment: What output are you trying to get?  You neglected to specify what you're trying to do, and your words are unclear.  The code you posted works just as you told it to do: it sorts the dict entries and returns the first element of each value, in that sorted order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for record in zip(*d.values()):
    print(record)
```

gives you each 'record' as a list of values, for example:

```
columns = ','.join(d)
placeholders = ','.join('?' for _ in d)

for record in zip(*d.values()):
    sql = f'INSERT INTO table({columns}) VALUES({placeholders})'
    your_db.execute(sql, record)
```

Comment: I'm not a genius at SQL, however this might lead to injection if SQL query parameters aren't used.

Comment: @Xiddoc: but they are, aren't they?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that by using python string formatting, you will be placing the values of `columns` and `placeholders` directly into the string, which is then executed in the `.execute()` method.

Comment: @Xiddoc look again `placeholders` contains the placeholders string only, the values are not used at the SQL query building, only in the execute, where they belong

Comment: Thnak you for your reply.But why when I print placeholders I only get "?,?,?,?,?,?"

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally your code helped me!

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip` you can read the list of data by rows, to build the rows to send to the DB. Then with [`cursor.executemany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany) you can pass a list of values that will be used in the parametrized query

```
keys = ','.join(d.keys())
param_placeholder = ','.join(['%s'] * len(d.keys()))
values = list(zip(*d.values()))
query = f"INSERT INTO MY_TABLE ({keys}) VALUES ({param_placeholder})"

cursor.executemany(query, values)
```

That is the same as

```
query = f"INSERT INTO MY_TABLE ({keys}) VALUES ({param_placeholder})"
for row in zip(*d.values()):
    cursor.execute(query, row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you're sorting the dict based on keys ->

```
test =','.join(str(d[x][0]) for x in sorted(d))
```

The result of sorted(d) is ->

```
['AcceptedDate',
 'Account',
 'CompanyName',
 'EulaVersion',
 'MachGuid',
 'Meter',
 'SoftwareVersion']
```

Now, if you take the 1st value from this sorted list you'll get ->

```
20210226,314113801,SN2000 TEST,2018v01FXRSSWO,{B2B94738-B031-46B2-9D94-F54EEF46BE82},000413031,FXRS1810
```

If you don't perform the sort operation and join ->

```
test =','.join(str(d[x][0]) for x in d)
# prints '000413031,314113801,20210226,2018v01FXRSSWO,FXRS1810,SN2000 TEST,{B2B94738-B031-46B2-9D94-F54EEF46BE82}'
```